# Building R packages with Packrat and AppVeyor

Tags: r, r-package, appveyor, packrat

Can someone point me towards a working example where [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) is used with [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/) to build an R package?  Searching through Google and GitHub, I can't find any packrat-enable package that uses AppVeyor.

Does the appveyor.yml file need to change?  Are there some settings I need to add through the AppVeyor website?

I have a very minimal package (`testthat` is the only dependency) that broke  AppVeyor builds.  Here is the [code frozen for that commit](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/Premiss/tree/f110944be3e1b02d53ffbe69b71fc5d2d9dd6615).  Here is the [AppVeyor log](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/wibeasley/premiss/build/1.0.10).

(If this SO question sounds familiar, I'm about to [ask a similar question for Travis-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997095/building-r-packages-with-packrat-and-travis-ci).)

Comment: are you building with windows? it says your rtools is not compatible (or the rtools on the server)

Comment: yes, AppVeyor is Windows only, although @krlmlr's approach (which I'm using; https://github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor/blob/master/scripts/appveyor-tool.ps1) calls MinGW and MSYS.  Despite the compatibility message, I don't think the rtools version is a problem.  I receive the same warning message on my desktop, and it's not been a problem.

Comment: I looked into this a little more.  The RTools compatibility message appeared before introducing Packrat, and the builds completed successfully. (eg, https://ci.appveyor.com/project/wibeasley/premiss/build/1.0.9#L134).  Also, Hadley added version information for RTools 3.3 ten days ago (https://github.com/hadley/devtools/commit/6fe9509c80cd7a51f5c1275e3ee4aa80b7659f28).  It looks like the scripts install the stable devtools from the Ubuntu repository (not CRAN or GitHub), so these messages might be showing for a while (https://github.com/krlmlr/r-travis/blob/master/scripts/travis-tool.sh#L117).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the solution here is similar to the [same question for Travis-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009579/using-r-package-source-files-in-packrat-rather-than-cran-with-travis-ci?rq=1).

Here's an example of an `appveyor.yml` file that will enable you to use packrat packages in your package:

```
# DO NOT CHANGE the "init" and "install" sections below

# Download script file from GitHub
init:
  ps: |
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
        Invoke-WebRequest http://raw.github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor/master/scripts/appveyor-tool.ps1 -OutFile "..\appveyor-tool.ps1"
        Import-Module '..\appveyor-tool.ps1'
install:
  ps: Bootstrap

# Adapt as necessary starting from here

environment:
  global:
   WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS: 0
   USE_RTOOLS: true

build_script:
  - R -e  "0" --args --bootstrap-packrat

test_script:
  - travis-tool.sh run_tests

on_failure:
  - 7z a failure.zip *.Rcheck\*
  - appveyor PushArtifact failure.zip

artifacts:
  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.log'
    name: Logs

  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.out'
    name: Logs

  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.fail'
    name: Logs

  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.Rout'
    name: Logs

  - path: '\*_*.tar.gz'
    name: Bits

  - path: '\*_*.zip'
    name: Bits
```

The important parts that differ from [the template](https://github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor/blob/master/sample.appveyor.yml) are:

```
 environment:
      global:
       WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS: 0
       USE_RTOOLS: true

    build_script:
      - R -e  "0" --args --bootstrap-packrat
```

This enables Rtools for the build, and loads the packrat packages.

It's also important to note that we are excluding `- travis-tool.sh install_deps` because that would cause the packages you depend on to be downloaded from CRAN, rather than built from your packrat directory.

Here's an example of an appveyor build for a simple R package where this is working: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/benmarwick/javaonappveyortest/build/1.0.21